# Test SSH private key passphrase (brute-force)

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, ssh-keys, brute-force

I have a problem with writing Python script which brute-force SSH private key passphrase for `/.ssh/id_rsa` file. I am using `ssh-add` command that ask passphrase until you enter it.

But script fail with error:

> ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

I don't understand why.

Tried all variations of subprocess module with `.Popen`, `.call` and etc. But I think most suitable for my situation is:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('ssh-add id_rsa', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
p.stdin.write(str('password'))
```

Expected password request, like `"Enter passphrase for id_rsa"`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use Paramiko, instead of hassling with an external console tool.

Use [`RSAKey` class (or `DSSKey`, `ECDSAKey`, `Ed25519Key`)](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html):

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(filename, passphrase)
```

It throws an exception, if the passphrase is wrong.